# Can't start jBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am trying to start jBoss. When i start the server,I am getting following lines on my console.

14:41:25,969 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA

14:41:26,743 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA

14:41:27,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.2.Final-SNAPSHOT "Brontes" starting

and shows a log saying that "starting server jBoss AS 1.7 has encountered a problem".I increased the timeouts. but it doesn't works.I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Is that the entire output? Can you provide the full log that shows "starting server jBoss AS 1.7 has encountered a problem"

Comment: I changed jdk version to 1.7 initially it was 1.8 and was working on jBoss AS 7.1. Now its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1 will not start successfully with Java 1.8.
[here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?start=0&tstart=0) the forum thread of the issue.

If you really need to use Java 1.8 consider using WildFly